# is function $f(x)=(-1)^{n} n^{p}$ integrable according to Riemann

Tags: calculus, integration, functional-analysis

I have this: $$f(x)=(-1)^{n} n^{p}, x\in [\frac{1}{1+n},\frac{1}{n}) $$
$$n \in N $$
$$E \in [0;1)$$
I have to check out if this function is integrable by Riemann.
I have an answer that if $p \geq 2$ is NOT integrable by Riemann, but I don't have any ideas how to prove it. Does anybody have some ideas?

Comment: For $p\ge2$ the area of each interval does not go to zero.

Comment: It also depends on what you mean by "integrable by Riemann". For $p > 0, f$ is unbounded, and therefore this becomes an improper integral. So if you are referring directlly to the definition of the Riemann integral, the answer is it is only integrable for $p = 0$. However, if you allow improper integrals, then it is integrable whenever $\sum_n (-1)^n\left(\frac {n^p}n - \frac {n^p}{1+n}\right)$ converges